# Materializecss select in standard form

Tags: materialize

I am trying to use the materializecss version of the selectbox. But when I try to submit, the name and value is not being passed with the form. Is this a bug or do I need to do something extra.

## Edit:

here is the code I use for the select:

```
<div class="col s12 m6 input-field">
    <select id="modules_edit" name="modules">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Kies de modules</option>
        <option value="Progress">Voortgang</option>
    </select>
    <label>Modules</label>
</div>
```

I also initialize the plugin like described on [materializecss](https://materializecss.com)

Comment: Can you share some code or illustration?

Comment: Like you see in my code, the post form should at least have `modules` as parameter, but it just doesn't.

Comment: did you solve your problem

Comment: I kind of did, actually, I fixed it by letting the label point to the select by using the `for` attribute but I couldn't find out why it works like that.